# React Redux change state in container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to migrate login from simple call to API to saga. And when I receive the data I want to cut only one element from it and to not reload all the list, this logic was working with call.then method of changing the state.(commented code) My question is how can I change the state in the controller in order to obtain this result. Thank you.

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {fetchBlogPosts, deleteBlogPost} from '../../connectivity/blog/api.blog-post';
import Table from '../../components/BlogPost/Table';
import * as types from '../../constants/actionTypes';
import {REQUESTS} from '../../sagas/blog/list.blog.saga'

class List extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      blogPosts: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //method without saga
    // fetchBlogPosts()
    //   .then((data) => {
    //     this.setState(state => {
    //       state.blogPosts = data;
    //       return state;
    //     });
    //   })
    //   .catch((err) => {
    //     console.error('err', err);
    //   });

    this.props.dispatch({
      type: types.BLOGPOSTS__REQUESTED,
      payload: {
        blog: this.props.blogPosts
      }
    });
  }

  onDelete(id) {
    //method without saga
    // deleteBlogPost(id)
    //   .then((data) => {
    //     let blogPosts = this.state.blogPosts.filter((post) => {
    //       return id !== post.id;
    //     });
    //
    //     this.setState(state => {
    //       state.blogPosts = blogPosts;
    //       return state;
    //     });
    //   })
    //   .catch((err) => {
    //     console.error('err', err);
    //   });
    this.props.dispatch({
      type: types.BLOGPOST__DELETED__REQUESTED,
      payload: {
        blogPostId: id
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const isSubmitting = this.props.pageState.request.inProgress.indexOf(REQUESTS.BLOGPOSTS__DOREQUESTBLOGPOSTS__SAGA) > -1;
    // let blogPosts = this.state.blogPosts;
    let blogPosts = this.props.blogPosts;

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>BLOG POSTS: </h3>
        <Table blogPosts={blogPosts}
               onDelete={this.onDelete.bind(this)}
               auth={this.props.auth}
               isSubmitting={isSubmitting}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

List.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  pageState: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth,
    blogPosts: state.blog.blogPosts,
    pageState: state
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(List);
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970400/react-redux-store-state-change-is-not-working/47970432#47970432

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem by sending a not Filtered list to delete action in the saga where after I am filtering I send it back with a payload.

```
onDelete(id) {
    this.props.dispatch({
      type: types.BLOGPOST__DELETED__REQUESTED,
      payload: {
        blogPostId: id,
        fullBlogPosts: this.props.blogPosts
      }
    });
  }
```

saga:

```
export function *doDeleteBlogPost(action) {

  try {

    const {blogPostId, fullBlogPosts} = action.payload;

    yield put({
      type: types.REQUEST__STARTED,
      payload: {
        requestFrom: REQUESTS.BLOGPOSTS__DODELETEBLOGPOST__SAGA
      }
    });

    const responseBody = yield call(api.deleteBlogPost, blogPostId);
    const blogPosts = fullBlogPosts.filter((post) => {
            return blogPostId !== post.id;
          });

    yield put({
      type: types.BLOGPOST__DELETED__SUCCEEDED,
      payload: {
        message: responseBody,
        blogPosts
      }
    }); ...
```